# Simplify complex catia model

Tags: cad, catia

I have a very complex CAD model of a car, and my task is to present it in VR. Since it's so complex, every single screw and stuff is in there, it currently is impossible to work with.
Unfortunately, I'm a total Catia beginner. Is there any way to get a model that only includes the visible surface and reduces the amount of data?

Answer (score 0):

With the ***DMO-license (DMU Optimizer 2)*** you can use the function called ***Silhoutte*** which will create the enveloping hull. But with ***Silhoutte*** model size will not decrease, but even increase.

So requiring a small model it might make more sense to use the function ***Simplification*** - also in DMO workbench. In my tests the model size (.cgr) was reduced to **1/10 of the original size** (Catia product with parts).

Results can be saved in formats *.cgr, .wrl, .model* or *.stl*.

More information in Catia docu:
http://catiadoc.free.fr/online/CATIAfr_C2/dmougCATIAfrs.htm